# static_cast in C++

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I was working on Circle class that is a child of Shape class and I have some tests that I have to pass that requires me to do some casting

```
    class Shape {
        friend bool operator == (const Shape& lhs, const Shape& rhs) {
            return (lhs._x == rhs._x) && (lhs._y == rhs._y);}
    
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& lhs, Shape& rhs) {
            return lhs >> rhs._x >> rhs._y;}
    
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& lhs, const Shape& rhs) {
            return lhs << rhs._x << " " << rhs._y;}
          ...


 class Circle: public Shape {
            friend bool operator == (const Circle& lhs, const Circle& rhs) {
                return (lhs._radius == rhs. _radius) && static_cast<Shape>(lhs) == rhs;} // this line
              ...
```

How it's different if I did it this way? What's better?

```
   class Circle: public Shape {
                friend bool operator == (const Circle& lhs, const Circle& rhs) {
                    return (lhs._radius == rhs. _radius) && static_cast<const Shape&>(lhs) == rhs;}
```

Comment: Why cast to another type and rely on implicit conversions when you can call `Shape::operator==()` directly and explicitly? Explicit is always better than implicit.

Comment: You want use `dynamic_cast` and check for `nullptr` at runtime; i.e., check to make sure its a circle first and then, if it is, compare its attributes.

Comment: @wcochran No need to use `dynamic_cast` in this case, since it's casting _from_ a derived class _to_ a base class.